# pyspark error: not enough values to unpack(expected 3, got 2)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following data

```
my_data=["Sentence1",['a','b','c'],"Sentence2",['d','e'],"Sentence3",['f']]
```

and want to convert the input data to dataframe using pyspark  2.2  as

```
---------------------------------
| ID | Sentence  | label        |
---------------------------------
| 01 | Sentence1 |['a','b','c'] |
| 02 | Sentence2 |['d','e']     |
```

But when the do it with following code

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
to_row = Row('ID','Sentence', 'list')
df = spark.createDataFrame([to_row(i,s,l) for i,s,l in enumerate(my_data)])
```

I get the following error

> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you copied and pasted [code you don't understand](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48290759/8371915) so:

- `enumerate`:

  > yields pairs containing a count (from
  >     start, which defaults to zero) and a value yielded by the iterable argument.
  >    enumerate is useful for obtaining an indexed list:
  >
  > ```
  > (0, seq[0]), (1, seq[1]), (2, seq[2]), ...
  > ```

  With `mydata` it will yield

  ```
  [(0, 'Sentence1'),
   (1, ['a', 'b', 'c']),
   (2, 'Sentence2'),
   (3, ['d', 'e']),
   (4, 'Sentence3'),
   (5, ['f'])]
  ```

  which is not useful at all.
- This because your data should be not

  ```
  ["Sentence1",['a','b','c'],"Sentence2",['d','e'],"Sentence3",['f']]
  ```

  but

  ```
  [("Sentence1",['a','b','c']),("Sentence2",['d','e']),("Sentence3",['f'])]
  ```

  if you want to connect records.
- If it was in this form, unpacking with

  ```
  i,s,l
  ```

  wouldn't work because pattern doesn't match the data. Matching pattern would be

  ```
  i, (s, l)
  ```
- Combined:

  ```
  from itertools import islice

  spark.createDataFrame([(x, y, z) for x, (y, z) in enumerate(zip(
      islice(my_data, 0, len(my_data), 2),
      islice(my_data, 1, len(my_data), 2)))
  ], ("id", "sentence", "label"))
  ```

  where

  ```
  islice(my_data, m, len(my_data), n)
  ```

  takes every n-th item from list starting from the m-th one, and `zip(seq1, seq2)` merges sequences into:

  ```
  [(seq1[0], seq2[0]), (seq1[1], seq2[1]), ... ]
  ```

  and `enumerate` converts it to

  ```
  [(0, (seq1[0], seq2[0])), (1, (seq1[1], seq2[1])), ... ]
  ```

Please consider learning the language before switching to more advanced tools.