# convert nested list to Dataframe : Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I tried to convert nested listed to Dataframe by following the answers in this link

[List to DataFrame in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48290759/list-to-dataframe-in-pyspark)

```
my_data =[['apple','ball','ballon'],['cat','camel','james'],['none','focus','cake']]
from pyspark.sql import Row
R = Row('ID', 'words')
spark.createDataFrame([R(i, x) for i, x in enumerate(my_data)]).show() 
​
```

But I obtain this error  :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-147-780a8d7196df> in <module>()
----> 5 spark.createDataFrame([R(i, x) for i, x in enumerate(my_data)]).show()

F:\spark\spark\python\pyspark\sql\session.py in createDataFrame(self, data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)

--> 689             rdd, schema = self._createFromLocal(map(prepare, data), schema)

F:\spark\spark\python\pyspark\sql\session.py in _createFromLocal(self, data, schema)

--> 424         return self._sc.parallelize(data), schema

F:\spark\spark\python\pyspark\context.py in parallelize(self, c, numSlices)

--> 484         jrdd = self._serialize_to_jvm(c, numSlices, serializer)

F:\spark\spark\python\pyspark\context.py in _serialize_to_jvm(self, data, parallelism, serializer)

--> 493         tempFile = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, dir=self._temp_dir)


~\Anaconda3\lib\tempfile.py in NamedTemporaryFile(mode, buffering, encoding, newline, suffix, prefix, dir, delete)
    547         flags |= _os.O_TEMPORARY
    548 
--> 549     (fd, name) = _mkstemp_inner(dir, prefix, suffix, flags, output_type)
    550     try:
    551         file = _io.open(fd, mode, buffering=buffering,

~\Anaconda3\lib\tempfile.py in _mkstemp_inner(dir, pre, suf, flags, output_type)
    258         file = _os.path.join(dir, pre + name + suf)
    259         try:
--> 260             fd = _os.open(file, flags, 0o600)
    261         except FileExistsError:
    262             continue    # try again

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\*****\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\spark-e340269d-a29e-4b95-90d3-c424a04fcb0a\\pyspark-f7fce557-e11b-47c9-b7a5-81e72a360b36\\tmp7n0s97t2'
```

Comment: That error seems unrelated to what you're trying to do. Try to create an simple DataFrame: `spark.createDataFrame([(1,),(2,)], ["col1"]).show()`

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your reply.  I tried to create simple data frame and I obtained the same error again

Comment: I tried to run pyspark from newfolder, I have created  the dataframe from nested list without any problem. but it doesn't work on the first folder what is the problem??

Comment: @Sidhom please provide more information on how you are running and what do you mean by first folder?

Answer (score 2):

i was getting the same error from jupyter notebook/pyspark.
it worked after restarting the notebook kernel.

Comment: click on Kernel > Restart &Clear Output  in Jupyter notebook