# How to create Spark table with nested list

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

How can I use this answer ([List to DataFrame in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48290759/list-to-dataframe-in-pyspark)or) a new answer to create a table using spark for nested list?

```
lst = [{'sfObject': 'event',
  'objID': 'Id',
  'interimRun': 'True',
  'numAttributes_Total': 140,
  'numAttributes_Compounded': 0,
  'numAttributes_nonCompounded': 140,
  'chunks': 1,
  'compoundStatus': 'False',
  'allAttributes': ['Id',
   'RecordTypeId',
   'WhoId',
   'Advisor_Team__c’,…],
  'compoundAttributes': [],
  'nonCompoundAttributes': ['Id',
   'RecordTypeId',
   'WhoId',
   'WhatId’…]},
 {'sfObject': 'fund__c',
  'objID': 'Id',
  'interimRun': 'False',
  'numAttributes_Total': 40,
  'numAttributes_Compounded': 0,
  'numAttributes_nonCompounded': 40,
  'chunks': 1,
  'compoundStatus': 'False',
  'allAttributes': ['Id',
   'IsDeleted',
   'Name’…],
  'compoundAttributes': [],
  'nonCompoundAttributes': ['Id',
   'IsDeleted',
   'Name',
   'RecordTypeId’…]}]
```

I want to create to store this list into a table so need its structure to be like this:

The link below is an image of table I need created using the above lst:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0pOO.png)

This nested list will have up to 30 different items, so the answer will need to dynamically create up to 30 rows for each item.

Thank you!

Comment: Hey, not sure if the image loads up properly. Btw, you may want to check out ArrayType :)

Comment: Sorry about the image. It looks like i need to have 15 reputation pts to post one...the one attached is super dark i can't even see it properly. Can you please expand on ArrayType suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have a list of dictionaries, run the following. It will infer the schema.

```
df = sc.parallelize(lst).toDF()
```

If you want to treat it as a table to run SQL queries on, run:

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df_table")
new_df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM df_table")
```

Comment: Thank you! This did the trick. However, I got this message "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py:375: UserWarning: Using RDD of dict to inferSchema is deprecated. Use pyspark.sql.Row instead
  warnings.warn("Using RDD of dict to inferSchema is deprecated. "

As a bonus, how can I use "pyspark.sql.Row" to achieve the same results? Thanks!